# Can a CTC contaning spacetime be purely electric?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, curvature, closed-timelike-curve

Take a time-oriented Lorentzian manifold $(M, g)$ where $M$ is a topological 4-manifold and $g$ a Lorenzian metric.

Assume such a spacetime contains a CTC.

Since the manifold is time-oriented, one can take a globally defined time-like vector field $u$ over the manifold.

A metric is called *Purely Electric* at point $p \in M$ if and only if there exists a neighbourhood around $p$ over which the Weyl tensor $C$ satisfies:
$$u_a g^{ab} C_{bc[de} u_{f]}=0$$

In 3+1 dimensions one can equivalently define Pure Electricity by introduction of the tensor:
$$H_{ab} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{acef} {C^{ef}}_{bd} u^c u^d$$

as vanishing of the magnetic part of the Weyl tensor $C_{-}$:

$${(C_{-})^{ab}}_{cd} = 2 \epsilon^{abef} u_{e} u_{[c} H_{d]f} + 2 \epsilon_{cdef} u^e u^{[a} H^{b]f}=0 $$

My question is:

**If there can exist a neighbourhood contaning the CTC, over which the metric is purely electric.**

---

PS: One already knows from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462046/503363) that strong causality and pure electricity are LOCALLY two orthogonal conditions.

Comment: Does Minkowski space with time identified count

Comment: Is it possible to localise such construct? Like identifying an open bounded subset of the real space at two times in the Minkowski case. @Slereah Is it stable against perturbations? What about the first case where the open subset is the whole real space and not bounded?

Comment: Also, Gödel universe is purely electric and contains CTC. Re: stable against perturbations. What do you mean? Gravitational waves generically have both electric and magnetic components, so being PE is not a stable property.

Comment: The gravitational action as a functional of the metric and its derivatives can have points of extremum. Does this solution pertain to such extremum? Does this extremum(in case) resist perturbations in the metric and its derivates meaning it has harmonic/oscillatory modes(discrete or continuum) around the solution? @A.V.S.

Comment: @A.V.S. Do you know any other CTC contaning purely electric spacetimes? I'd really appreciate in case you share any. Thanks